# Notice Array to string in line 72

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

tengo el problema con un insertar en php el resto de modelos lo hacen perfecto menos este, dejo el código del insertar señalando la linea 72

```
public function Insertar($r){
        try {
            $sql="INSERT INTO reporte(reporte_id,reporte_ubicacion,reporte_compra,reporte_equipo,reporte_centro,reporte_observacion) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    //linea 72  $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array(
                $r->reporte_id,
                $r->reporte_ubicacion,
                $r->reporte_compra,
                $r->reporte_equipo,
                $r->reporte_centro,
                $r->reporte_observacion
            ));
            $id=$this->pdo->lastInsertId();
            return $id;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. Todo parece correcto, aunque depende de lo que haya en `$r` y en sus claves. El error parecería indicar que alguna de las claves de `$r` no es una cadena, sino un array. Crea un array separado con los parámetros para poder probarlo: `$params=array(
                $r->reporte_id,
                $r->reporte_ubicacion,
                $r->reporte_compra,
                $r->reporte_equipo,
                $r->reporte_centro,
                $r->reporte_observacion
            )`; Y luego `var_dump($params);` ahí verás el contenido de lo que realmente intentas enviar

Comment: O... haz un `var_dump($r);`, verificando que los valores de todas las claves que quieres usar en el `execute` tales como `reporte_id, reporte_ubicacion, reporte_compra`, etc son cadenas y no arrays.

Comment: Voy a mirar porque el insertar igual lo hace perfecto solo que me toca redireccionar manualmente a la lista entonces voy a mirar donde se lo estoy mandando mal

Comment: *`Array to string conversion`*  ocurre cuando tratas un array como si fuese una cadena. Es un mensaje del tipo `Notice`, lo cual significa que el código no falla por eso, pero puede que ese valor en  la BD se inserte como `NULL` porque realmente no obtienes el valor. Con un simple `var_dump` podrás ver cómo está constituido el array que estás mandando en el `execute`. A mi no me gusta demasiado encadenar métodos y pasar todo dentro de los métodos.  Me gusta crear variables porque es mucho más fácil depurar y el código es más claro y legible... por ejemplo:

Comment: `$stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($sql); $params=array(
                $r->reporte_id,
                $r->reporte_ubicacion,
                $r->reporte_compra,
                $r->reporte_equipo,
                $r->reporte_centro,
                $r->reporte_observacion
            ); $stmt->execute($params);` ... Así puedes depurar más facll, sea la preparación de la consulta que el array mismo que le pasas.

Comment: Inserta un numero ya que le estoy insertando el id de otra tabla porque la mayoría de atributos de esa tabla son llaves foraneas será por eso?

Comment: No entiendo bien tu comentario. Si el `Notice`  ocurre en la línea que indicas **significa que en esa línea hay un array que es tratado como una cadena** y es muy probable que sea una de las llaves de `$r` que usas en el `execute`
, que tiene a su vez un array anidado. ¿Hiciste la depuración con `var_dump` como te indiqué? ¿Qué muestra el `var_dump`? O sea, uno de estos valores: `$r->reporte_id, $r->reporte_ubicacion, $r->reporte_compra, $r->reporte_equipo, $r->reporte_centro, $r->reporte_observacion` no es una cadena, sino un array. Eso es lo que tienes que revisar.

Comment: Mire como inserto desde el controlador en esa tabla para que me entienda, ya lo publico

Comment: ¿No puedes hacer un `var_dump` como te he dicho? Es necesario ver los datos concretamente.

Comment: Listo ya le muestro lo que me bote

Answer (score 0):

```
public function CargarExcel(){
    require "PHPExcel/CargarExcel.php";
    foreach ($filas as $fila) {
        foreach ($fila as $valor) {
            if($valor['A']!="Nombre" && $valor['A']!=null){
            $this->model->setReporte_id($valor['A']);
            $this->model2->setUbi_ciu($valor['B']);
            $this->model2->setUbi_dep($valor['C']);
            $this->model2->setUbi_tipo_punto($valor['D']);
            $this->model2->setUbi_piso($valor['E']);
            $this->model2->setUbi_ubicacion_fisica($valor['F']);
            $id2=$this->model2->Insertar($this->model2);
            $this->model3->setCentro_nombre($valor['G']);
            $this->model3->setCentro_codigo($valor['H']);
            $this->model3->setCentro_categoria($valor['I']);
            $this->model3->setCentro_servicio(['J']);
            $id3=$this->model3->Insertar($this->model3);
            $this->model4->setEquipo_nom($valor['K']);
            $this->model4->setEquipo_mar($valor['L']);
            $this->model4->setEquipo_mod($valor['M']);
            $this->model4->setEquipo_serie($valor['N']);
            $this->model4->setEquipo_est($valor['O']);
            $this->model4->setEquipo_placa($valor['P']);
            $this->model4->setEquipo_docu($valor['Q']);
            $id4=$this->model4->Insertar($this->model4);
            $this->model5->setCompra_año($valor['R']);
            $this->model5->setCompra_costo($valor['S']);
            $this->model5->setCompra_adquisicion($valor['T']);
            $this->model5->setCompra_fecha_factura($valor['U']);
            $this->model5->setCompra_factura($valor['V']);
            $this->model5->setCompra_garantia($valor['W']);
            $this->model5->setCompra_ven_garantia($valor['X']);
            $this->model5->setCompra_soporte($valor['Y']);
            $this->model5->setCompra_descripcion($valor['Z']);
            $id5=$this->model5->Insertar($this->model5);
            //Este es el insertar que bota el Notice
            $this->model->setReporte_ubicacion($id2);
            $this->model->setReporte_centro($id3);
            $this->model->setReporte_equipo($id4);
            $this->model->setReporte_compra($id5);
            $this->model->setReporte_observacion($valor['AA']);
            $this->model->Insertar($this->model);
            }
        }
    }
    header("location:?c=reporte&a=Lista");

}
```